# Add css properties to a collection from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to add CSS properties on each element of a collection with jQuery. Any suggestions?

```
var jsonCss = {
    "color": "#555555",
    "font-weight": "bold",
    "text-align": "left"
};

var $tdCollection = $("tr:first-child").find("td:nth-child(2)"); //A collection of <td> elements
$.each($tdCollection, function(k, v){
    v.css(jsonCss);
})
```

Comment: use a class and add that class to the element you want to give css

Comment: Thank you for helping. I must use a JSON object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use an `each()` here, you can just apply the CSS settings to all elements within the jQuery object:

```
var cssObject = {
    "color": "#555555",
    "font-weight": "bold",
    "text-align": "left"
};

var $tdCollection = $("tr:first-child").find("td:nth-child(2)");
$tdCollecton.css(cssObject);
```

Also note that the object you define which holds the CSS rules is nothing to do with JSON at all - it's an object - hence why I changed its name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for...in`

```js
var jsonCss = {
  "color": "#555555",
  "font-weight": "bold",
  "text-align": "left"
};

var $tdCollection = $("tr:first-child").find("td:nth-child(2)");
for (var p in jsonCss) {
  $tdCollection.css(p, jsonCss[p]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td>Lorem</td><td>Lorem</td></tr>
</table>
```